# My very basic command is failing on cron but runs fine otherwise, in bash

Tags: bash, cron, debian, command-line-interface, sh

I'm trying this very basic thing, to output a random number:

```
NUMBER=$[ ( $RANDOM % 500 )  + 1 ]; echo $NUMBER > /tmp/out
```

It runs fine directly on the CLI in Debian, but when I try to cron this, either as is:

```
* * * * * NUMBER=$[ ( $RANDOM % 500 )  + 1 ]; echo $NUMBER > /tmp/out
```

Or in part of a script in various ways, it consistently fails in my email alerts as:

```
/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I'm very out of practice so I expect it's something glaring obvious. I've tried every bracketing type combo I can think of with no luck. What am I missing?

The full mail alerts I received were:

```
From: Cron Daemon 
Sent: Friday, February 01, 2013 2:41 PM
Subject: Cron <root@host> NUMBER=$[ ( $RANDOM (failed)

/bin/sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: `/bin/sh` (cron's default shell) is not the same as `bash` that you're testing your script on. If you want bash, then save that line in a file and have bash run it: `* * * * * /bin/bash /home/you/your_file.sh`

Comment: Thank you. This would have been obvious years ago. The things you forget...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to escaping the `%` sign, as F. Hauri points out, `cron` runs commands using `/bin/sh`, which doesn't necessarily support all the features that bash does.

```
* * * * * bash -c 'NUMBER=$[ ( $RANDOM \% 500 )  + 1 ]; echo $NUMBER > /tmp/out'
```

Or better yet, put the command into a script with `#!/bin/bash` and execute the script from your `crontab`.

Comment: Outstanding, thank you! You and F. Hauri have absolutely been wonderful here on clearing this.